# How to delete the date in top line from DatePicker?

Tags: android, datepicker

I need to remove the date in top line, see the image (it marker in yellow):

[image: Date Picker]

and this is my code:

```
final Calendar mCalender = Calendar.getInstance();
int mYear = mCalender.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int mMonth = mCalender.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int mDay = mCalender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),R.style.DatePicker,
          (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity(), mYear, mMonth, mDay);
```

and this the code from `layout` xml:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:hint="Date"
    android:onClick="getDate"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
```

what I should do for fix it?

alot of thanks :)

Comment: can you have also edittext?

Comment: no, I have one editText..

Comment: please share your all xml layout

Comment: my xml layout:  <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<EditText....>
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: thanks alot for you'r answer it very help to me :), now it work fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a dialog `title` where date is visible on top which you don't want to show.
Try this line of code to set title as empty :

```
  dialog.setTitle("");
```

Hope this works.

Comment: downvoted any reason please

Comment: yes, thanks for you, it now work from you'r answer :)